# Как заменить BillingClient.queryPurchases() на BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте , пытаюсь заменить  BillingClient.queryPurchases()  на  BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()  (нужно для перехода с версии 3 на 4  Google Play Billing Library)

Просит 2 аргумента  какие я не пойму не особо шарю в программировании .

//

Нужна помощь.

Весь код прилагаю ниже

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {


    public static final String PRODUCT_ID1 = "purchase";


    private BillingClient billingClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            mBillingClient(null);


    }

    public void mBillingClient (View view){
        // Устанавливаем соединение с клиентом биллинга
        // проверяем статус покупки из кеша Google Play Store
        // чтобы проверить, был ли товар уже приобретен ранее или возвращен

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                      Purchase.PurchasesResult queryPurchase = billingClient.queryPurchases(INAPP);
                      Purchase.PurchasesResult queryPurchase = billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync();
                    List<Purchase> queryPurchases = queryPurchase.getPurchasesList();
                    if (queryPurchases != null && queryPurchases.size() > 0) {
                        initiatePurchase();

                        for (int i = 0; i < queryPurchases.size(); i++) {
                            ArrayList<String> purchaseId = queryPurchases.get(i).getSkus();

                            if (TextUtils.equals(PRODUCT_ID1, (CharSequence) purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete1(null);

                            }

                        }
                    }


                        billingClient.endConnection();

                    }


                }


            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            }
        });
    }


    private void initiatePurchase() {
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

        skuList.add(PRODUCT_ID1);

        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(INAPP);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) { }



    public void payComplete1(View view)
    {    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\n" + " payComplete1 - Товар куплен 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();};




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это можно посмотреть в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchasesAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener)). Первым параметром должна быть строка, которая определяет тип запрашиваемых покупок (подписка или in-app). Вторым параметром является листенер (в нем вы можете обрабатывать результат вашего запроса)

```java
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
    BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP,
    (billingResult, list) -> {
        // ...
    }
);
```